# How would I use the SecurityPermissionAttribute correctly?

Tags: .net

In an old project I came across the following assembly attribute:

```
[assembly: SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, Execution = true)]
```

I [understand](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2004/08/30/222918.aspx) that this attribute instructs the clr to not load this dll if the required permissions aren't available. Is it a good practice to include such declarations in your project as a default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RequestMinimum` has never been very popular. In fact, most of the Code Access Security model never really gained much traction. Consequently, these areas were greatly reworked for .NET 4.0.

As of .NET 4.0, do not use `RequestMinimum` because it will be ignored.

These changes are explained in detail in the documentation for .NET 4.0, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233103(VS.100).aspx.